# What does "Invalid address specified to RtlFreeHeap( 06450000, 08387460 )" mean?

Tags: delphi, debugging, dll, heap-memory

Sometimes I experience random crashes in my Delphi program. My program halts, and the Debugger outputs:

**Invalid address specified to RtlFreeHeap( 06450000, 08387460 )**

What does that mean? And what can possibly cause it?

This is where the CPU Inspector stopped:

**77BA0845 C6052582BD7700   mov byte ptr [$77bd8225],$00**

Please note that they are very random (for me). Sometimes they don't appear at all.

I am using the **Skype4COM.dll** from Skype - there's no source though.

In case you need it, here is the code. I have commented most of the calls to Synchronize, so you know what they do.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// Execute
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
procedure TContactDeletor.Execute;
Var
  I             : Integer;
  UserObj       : PUser;
  User          : IUser;
  PauseEvent    : TEvent;
begin
  inherited;
  FreeOnTerminate       := True;
  if Terminated then
  Exit;

  CoInitialize(Nil);
  // The F-Flags are to make sure TSkype events do not fire (from my Main Thread)
  FAllowUI              := False;
  FUserIsBeingDeleted   := False;
  FUseGroupUsersEvent   := False;
  FUseRenameEvent       := False;
  SkypeThr              := TSkype.Create(Nil);
  SkypeThr.Attach(10,False);
  SkypeThr.Cache        := False;
  MyList                := TStringList.Create;
  PauseEvent            := TEvent.Create(True);
  try
  // This fills my Stringlist
  Synchronize(GrabList);
  if Terminated then Exit;


  iMax                  := MyList.Count;
  // This sets the Max of my Progressbar
  Synchronize(SetMax);
  Try
  for I := 0 to MyList.Count - 1 do
    begin

      {while SkypeThr.AttachmentStatus <> apiAttachSuccess do
      begin
        SkypeThr.Attach(10,False);
        Synchronize(Procedure Begin Log('Skype Unavailable - Trying to reconnect ...'); End);
        PauseEvent.WaitFor(5000);
      end;  }

      CurUser := '';
      User := SkypeThr.User[MyList[I]];
      CurUser := MyList[I];

      Try
      User.IsAuthorized := False;
      User.BuddyStatus := budDeletedFriend;
      Except on E:Exception do
      begin
       ExErr := E.Message;
       ExLog := 'Error while deleting contacts: ';
       ExMsg := 'An Error has occured while deleting contacts: ';
       Synchronize(
       Procedure
       Begin
        Log(ExLog+ExErr+sLineBreak+' - Last logged Handle: '+CurUser);
       End
       );    
      end;
      end;

      iProgress := I+1;
      // This updates my log and my progressbar.
      Synchronize(UpdatePG);
      PauseEvent.WaitFor(100);

      if (I mod 200 = 0) and (I > 0) then
        begin
          // Calls to Synchronize updates my log
          Synchronize(SyncPauseBegin);
          PauseEvent.WaitFor(3000);
          Synchronize(SyncPauseEnd);
        end;


    end;
  // Except
  Except on E:Exception do
  begin
   ExErr := E.Message;
   ExLog := 'Error while deleting contacts: ';
   ExMsg := 'An Error has occured while deleting contacts: ';
   Synchronize(
   Procedure
   Begin
    Log(ExMsg+ExErr+sLineBreak+' - Last logged Handle: '+CurUser);
    ErrMsg(ExMsg+ExErr+sLineBreak+sLineBreak+' - Last logged Handle: '+CurUser);
   End
   );
   Exit;
  end;
  end;
  // This synchronizes my visual list.
  Synchronize(SyncList);
  finally
   FUserIsBeingDeleted   := False;
   FUseGroupUsersEvent   := True;
   FUseRenameEvent       := True;
   FAllowUI              := True;
   Synchronize(
   Procedure
   Begin
   frmMain.UpdateStatusBar;
   PleaseWait(False);
   ToggleUI(True);
   end);
   PauseEvent.Free;
   SkypeThr.Free;
   MyList.Free;
   CoUninitialize;
  end;


end;
```

Comment: Sounds like you are allocating memory in one heap and trying to free it in another heap. My guess is that its a flaw in how you are driving this COM control, which is what is calling RtlFreeHeap I guess. Are you calling methods from different threads when you need to be calling them from the same thread?

Comment: Means you have corrupted your heap. Heap corruption is harder to track down and debug.  But since you are experiencing this error randomly, you can start looking for a Race condition.

Comment: @David - I use a few descendants from TThread, but they all have their own TSkype control. Also, only one descendant is running at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Najem was correct, it is because your heap is corrupted.  To debug it easier, you should enable [PageHeap](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286470), also, use the debug CRT (or debug delphi runtime) as much as possiable until you find out what's corrupting your memory.

A lot of the time, the corruption may only spill over a few bytes.  Then your application can run fine for a very long time, so you will not notice anything wrong until much later, if at all.

Try to exit your application cleanly when your looking for memory corruption bugs, dont just stop the debugger, when your process is exiting, it should "touch" most of the memory it allocated earlier and it will give you a chance to detect the failure.